# Load files from a list of file paths in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with a couple hundred file paths to text files which I would like to open, write / cut up pieces from it and save under a new name.

I've been Googling how to do this and found the module glob, but I can't figure out exactly how to use this.

Could you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: Thanks. I saw this page, of course, but it's not so straightforward to me how I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have specific paths to files, you won't need to glob module. The glob module is useful when you want to use path like `/user/home/someone/pictures/*.jpg`. From what I understand you have a file with normal paths.

You can use this code as a start:

```
with open('file_with_paths', 'r') as paths_list:
    for file_path in paths_list:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            # Do what you want with one of the files here.
```

Comment: This is great, very clear! Thanks! But for reason python can't fnd the files: 'No such file or directory'. Do you think these file paths are in the right format when the first file (P10088) is located in my working directory? P10088/10088-01-07-02/pca/SE1_5a0e110-5a0e6a1.evt

Comment: It all depends what is your `current working directory`. If the paths in your `file_with_paths` are relative to the directory in which you run your `python script.py` than it should be all right. You can check your current working directory with `os.getcwd()` and you can change it with `os.chdir()`. Check if those directories are what you expect.

Comment: The `open` function, if given a non-absolute path to files tries to open the file by combining result of `os.getcwd()` with what you give it as an argument. That's why it's important to make sure that `os.getcwd() + '/' + file_path` makes sense.

Comment: I think it make sense, except that the error message prints an \n after the file path, probably because there are enters after each file path. Does that matter at all?

Comment: @user90465 find out by passing `file_path.strip()` to the `open` function. `strip()` removes whitespace from the beginning and end of the string, so it'll get rid of the `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just traverse the file line by line and then take out what you want from that name. Later save/create it . Below sample code might help

```
with open('file_name') as f:
    for file_path in f:
        import os
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        absolute path = os.path.dirname(file_path)
        # change whatever you want to with above two and save the file
        # os.makedirs to create directry
        # os.open() in write mode to create the file
```

Let me know if it helps you

Comment: Thank you for this! Could you maybe exlplain a bit more about it? It's not very obvious to me what is what, and how to traverse over the files and change them.